# Issues with lookup and match multipe collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Having issues with aggregate and lookup in multiple stages. The issue is that I cannot match by `userId` In the last lookup. If I omit the `{ $eq: ['$userId', '$$userId'] }` it works and match by the other criteria. But not by the `userid`.

I've tried added pools as a let and use it as `{ $eq: ['$userId', '$$pools.userId'] }` in the last stage but that doesn't work either. I get an empty coupon array.

I get this with the below query. I think I need to use `$unwind` in some way? But haven't got that to work yet. Any pointers?

There is three collections total to be joined. First the userModel, it should contain pools and then the pools should contain a users coupons.

```
{
   "userId": "5df344a1372f345308dac12a", // Match this usedId with below userId coming from the coupon

   "pools": [
               {
                "_id": "5e1ebbc6cffd4b042fc081ab",
                "eventId": "id999",
                "eventStartTime": "some date",
                "trackName": "tracky",
                "type": "foo bar",
                "coupon": []
               }
            ]
  },
```

I need the coupon array to be filled with the correct data (below) which has a matching userId in it.

```
"coupon": [
                {
                    "eventId": "id999",
                    "userId": "5df344a1372f345308dac12a",  // This userId need to match the above one
                    "checked": true,
                    "pool": "a pool",
        }
```

poolProject:

```
const poolProject = {
    eventId: 1,
    eventStartTime: 1,
    trackName: 1,
    type: 1,
  };
```

Userproject:

```
const userProjection = {
    _id: {
      $toString: '$_id',
    },
    paper: 1,
    correctBetsLastWeek: 1,
    correctBetsTotal: 1,
    totalScore: 1,
    role: 1,
  };
```

The aggregate query

```
  const result = await userModel.aggregate([
{ $project: userProjection },
{
  $match: {
    $or: [{ role: 'User' },
      { role: 'SuperUser' }],
  },
},
{ $addFields: { userId: { $toString: '$_id' } } },
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'pools',
    as: 'pools',
    let: { eventId: '$eventId' },
    pipeline: [
      { $project: poolProject },
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $in: ['$eventId', eventIds],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'coupons',
          as: 'coupon',
          let: { innerUserId: '$$userId' },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: ['$userId', '$$innerUserId'],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
]);
```

Thanks for any input!

Edit:
If i move the second lookup (coupon) so they are in the same "level" it works but i would like to have it inside of the pool. If I add `as: 'pools.coupon'`, in the last lookup it overwrites the lookedup pool data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access fields with the `$$` prefix it means they are defined as "special" system variables by Mongo.

We don't know exactly how Mongo the magic happens but you're naming two variables with the same name, which causes a conflict as it seems.

So either remove `userId: '$userId'` from the first lookup as you're not even using it.

Or rename or second `userId: '$userId'` a different name like `innerUserId: '$userId'` to avoid conflicts when you access it.

Just dont forget to change `{ $eq: ['$userId', '$$userId'] }` to `{ $eq: ['$userId', '$$innerUserId'] }` after.

EDIT:

Now that its clear theres no field `userId` in `pools` collection just change the variable in the second `lookup` collection from:

```
let: { innerUserId: '$userId' } //userId does not exist in pools.
```

To:

```
let: { innerUserId: '$$userId' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it did not work. Tried both removin and renaming but still only get an empty coupon array

Comment: Well the syntax is correct, so its either you have a type mis-match between the collection like `ObjectId` and `string` OR the other option is that `poolProject` doesn't `project` the `userId` field, i can't know as you didn't post it.

Comment: There is no userId in the pool as it's a 'generic' collection. The userIds are in the top level userModel and in the third level coupon. Also i'm using userId as strings and not ObjectId i think? I've updated the question with the current query and with the projections

Comment: ah, the data you posted on top suggest otherwise ,in this case its an easy fix as you just had a minor syntax error. i specified it in my edit.

Comment: also if its a "generic" collection why not match the coupons first to boost performance?

Comment: hmm getting `MongoError: Use of undefined variable: userId` when adding the new let in your edit to the second lookup. Tried a couple of versions of  `{ $eq: ['$userId', '$$innerUserId'] },` but still the same error.

Comment: you didn't change the let, just copy what i said. `let: { innerUserId: '$$userId' }` instead of what you have now.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the current query and getting the `MongoError: Use of undefined variable: userId`

Comment: Because you removed it from the first lookup, when I wrote you should remove it, it was when you weren't using it and I thought pools had a userid

Comment: Ah i see. It works now! Thank you so much for your time and patience! Much appreciated!